# Как одновременно использовать aiohttp web.run_app и AsyncIOScheduler?

Tags: python, asyncio, aiohttp, apscheduler

код выглядит так:

```
async def main():
    .....
    scheduler = AsyncIOScheduler()
    scheduler.add_job(check_and_post, trigger='interval', seconds=15)
    scheduler.add_job(delete_old_messages, 'cron', day_of_week='mon', hour=19, minute=25)
    scheduler.start()


def setup_webhooks():
    .......
    .....
    web.run_app(app, host=config.WEB_SERVER_HOST, port=config.WEB_SERVER_PORT)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
    setup_webhooks()
```

в результате scheduler запускается, но не работает, т.к. его ивент луп перебивается run_app'ом.